# How to get email and username from a Facebook login button?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, response

We want to allow users to log into our site though Facebook. But how can I get Facebook's button to return the user's email and username?

right after the body tags:

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : '331796760587640',
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            version    : 'v2.9'
        });
        FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>
```

in the nav bar (or login menu):

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="small" data-button-type="login_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false"></div>
```

but looks like this just logs them into Facebook, not to our site. How can i get the user's email and username after they click the button? Something like this:

```
var username = ???
var email = ???
attempt_login(username, email);
```

Comment: Read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/accesstokens

Comment: i saw that but i still have no clue how to use it. I tried FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    console.log("FB email: "+response.email);
    console.log("FB name: "+response.name);
   });     in there but the email and name are undefined

Comment: Also FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    console.log("FB API");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
   }); gives an error: {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500,"fbtrace_id":"E+UtQncZIZ0"}}

Answer (score 2):

You wont be able to get that information from the login response. You will need to add a second call to `me?fields=name,email` using the access token from the login response.